# Recover from "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception"

Tags: php, soap, fatal-error

I already have functional code, but I'm currently trying to find ways to break it so that I can find exceptions to catch. The code below connects to a Bluecat/Proteus API and attempts to allocate a DHCP Reservation against a list of IP/MAC combos being uploaded via CSV. Knowing the people who would be using this tool, typos in the IP and/or MAC are possible and there could potentially be hundreds of items to process in a given CSV upload.

To test, I'm passing an IP with an invalid octet and a MAC with the same problem. Unfortunately, I've come across this error type and from what I've searched for, there is no way to gracefully catch and log the error and move on to the next item in the list to be processed.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$client = new SoapClient("...server with WSDL thingy...");
$client->login($_SESSION['user'], $_SESSION['pass']);

# List of items to process taken from a form upload on a preceeding page
# List saved as array in 'csv'

foreach ($_SESSION['csv'] as $i=>$row) {

try {
$_SESSION['csv'][$i] = array_combine($_SESSION['keys'], $row);

$client->assignIP4Address('5',$_SESSION['csv'][$i]['ip4Address'],$_SESSION['csv'][$i]['macAddress'],'','MAKE_DHCP_RESERVED','');
}

catch (Exception $e) {
#Exception messaging goes here
}
}
?>
```

The specific errors I'm getting are:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Server] Invalid octet value: 666 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\proteustool\dhcp_reservations.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\proteustool\dhcp_reservations.php(30): SoapClient->__call('assignIP4Addres...', Array) #1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\proteustool\dhcp_reservations.php(30): SoapClient->assignIP4Address('5', '10.166.28.666', 'cc:dd:ee:ff:00:...', '', 'MAKE_DHCP_RESER...', '') #2 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\proteustool\dhcp_reservations.php on line 30

and

> SoapFault: Invalid octet value: 666 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\proteustool\dhcp_reservations.php on line 30

Note that the error kills the script at the invalid IP as it comes first in the list of arguments for the method call to the soap provider. I have no clue what the error for the invalid MAC would be yet, but I'm guessing something similar.

The invalid IP/MAC octets are as such: x.x.x.666 and xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:ZZ

Is there any way to catch this specific type of fatal error and continue processing with the next item in the foreach loop? As I said, there could be hundreds of rows in the source CSV and having the script die at some random place because of a typo would be a pain in the ass.

This question is for PHP 5.6, just to be complete.

Comment: validate address before processing it?

Comment: Was thinking that. Going to have to figure out how to do that, but that's not a big deal. This is my first time using php for anything so it's kind of on-the-job learning with a low priority project.

Comment: not hard: `if (filter_var($_SESSION['csv'][$i]['ip4Address'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) { ...}`

Comment: Nice. I’m only on day 3 of learning php, so I haven’t come across filters yet. Thanks, this will do perfectly!

Comment: Then add `if (filter_var($_SESSION['csv'][$i]['macAddress'], FILTER_VALIDATE_MAC)) { ...}`

Comment: Is there a construct in php for chaining/staging tests? ie. if a variable passes the first validation, move onto the next. If not, catch the error and break the loop and move to the next item, etc? I originally made this tool in Powershell and I know how to do the chaining there, but again, php is a whole new frontier of syntax for me.

Comment: fleshed out code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($_SESSION['csv'] as $i=>$row){


        $_SESSION['csv'][$i] = array_combine($_SESSION['keys'],$row);

        if (filter_var($_SESSION['csv'][$i]['ip4Address'],FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && filter_var($_SESSION['csv'][$i]['macAddress'],FILTER_VALIDATE_MAC)){
            $client->assignIP4Address('5',$_SESSION['csv'][$i]['ip4Address'],$_SESSION['csv'][$i]['macAddress'],'','MAKE_DHCP_RESERVED','');
        }else{
            // nothing actually it will just move on to then next row
            //you could record the faliur or alert the user if required
        }
    }
```

Try\catch removed as you did not seem to be doing anything with it

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful. I had to add a couple more things to test the actual allocation step, but it's working nicely now. Here is what I ended up with, in case anyone was curious:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['csv'] as $i=>$row){

$_SESSION['csv'][$i] = array_combine($_SESSION['keys'],$row);

if (filter_var($_SESSION['csv'][$i]['ip4Address'],FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) && filter_var($_SESSION['csv'][$i]['macAddress'],FILTER_VALIDATE_MAC)){

    $success = true;

    try {
        $client->assignIP4Address('5',$_SESSION['csv'][$i]['ip4Address'],$_SESSION['csv'][$i]['macAddress'],'','MAKE_DHCP_RESERVED','');
        }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Failure: " . $_SESSION['csv'][$i]['ip4Address'] . "/" . $_SESSION['csv'][$i]['macAddress'] . " could not be allocated. Cause: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
        $success = false;
        }
    if ($success) {
        echo "Success: " . $_SESSION['csv'][$i]['ip4Address'] . " has been allocated to " . $_SESSION['csv'][$i]['macAddress'] . "<br>";
    }   
}
else{
    echo "Failure: " . $_SESSION['csv'][$i]['ip4Address'] . "/" . $_SESSION['csv'][$i]['macAddress'] . " could not be allocated. Please check that the IP or MAC is valid. <br>";
    }
}
```